# Django AttributeError and query does not exist error

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

File "C:\Users\NICSI\Desktop\lastnow\mynew\cheque\models.py", line 39, in **st
r**
    return (self.related.relation.username).title()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'relation'
[28/Sep/2018 12:36:49] "GET /admin/cheque/mycheque/ HTTP/1.1" 500 301999
Exception Value:
Signs matching query does not exist.
DJANGO throw these two errors how could i resolve this to show the relation between user and these details

```js
models.py
class Signs(models.Model):
     relation = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     department = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=1000, help_text="User Department")
     mobile = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=1000, help_text="User Mobile")

     
     def __str__(self):
      return (self.relation.username).title()
     class Meta:
       verbose_name_plural = "Registration Information"
    class Mycheque(models.Model):
     related = models.ForeignKey(Signs, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
     to_pay = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
     amount = models.BigIntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
     amount_in_words = models.CharField(max_length=10000, null=True, blank=True)
     vouchar_no = models.BigIntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
     dated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
     cheque_no = models.BigIntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
     cheque_date = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
     account_no = models.BigIntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
     
     def save(self):
       self.dated = datetime.now()
       super(Mycheque, self).save()
     
     def __str__(self):
      return (self.related.relation.username).title()
     class Meta:
       verbose_name_plural = "Single Cheque Of Users"
```

```html
views.py
    def mycheque(request):
      if request.method == "POST":
       userdata = User.objects.get(username = request.user)
       user_data = Signs.objects.get(relation_id=userdata.id)
       if userdata.check_password(passwd) == True:
        to_p = request.POST['topay']
        amnt = request.POST['amount1']
        amnt_in_words = request.POST['amount_string'] 
        vouch_no = request.POST['voucharno']
        d = request.POST['date'] 
        cheq_no = request.POST['chequeno']
        cheq_date = request.POST['chequedate']
        acc_no = request.POST['accountno']
        single = Mycheque(to_pay=to_p, amount=amnt, amount_in_words=amnt_in_words, vouchar_no=vouch_no, dated=d, cheque_no=cheq_no, cheque_date=cheq_date, account_no=acc_no)
        single.save()
        messages.success(request, "Your Cheque is created") 
         
      else:
       messages.error(request, "Please Try again...")
      return render(request, 'cheque/mycheque.html', {})
```

Comment: Can you share the full traceback?

Comment: yes i share pic of errors

Comment: why is it so hard to simply *copy* the text in the question?

Comment: ok i will do this

Answer (score 0):

## `AttributeError`

The error originates from the fact that the `Mycheque.related` relation is NULLable: it is possible to set it to `NULL`.

This means that for some `Mycheque`s, the `self.related` object will be `None`, and therefore `self.related.relation` will error.

You will thus to add some logic to the `__str__` to handle that case, for example:

```
def __str__(self):
    if self.related:
        return self.related.relation.username.title()
    else:
        return 'no related!'
```

That being said, I find the `__str__` function rather "weird": the textual representation of a `Mycheque` only takes the `related.relation` object into account? So you should consider redesigning this.

The same "scanario" can happen on multiple places, so you should run a search and fix it accordingly

## `Singns` does not exists

This is probably due to the line:

```
user_data = Signs.objects.get(relation_id=userdata.id)
```

The strange thing is here that you do nothing with the `user_data` variable at all, so  - given you implemented the view correctly - can remove the line.

That being said the line itself makes no sense: you query a `ForeignKey` in reverse, that means that for a `User` object, there can be zero, one, or multiple `Signs` objects. So it makes more sense to use `.filter(..)` since if there are no related `Signs` (or multiple) this query will error.

## Refactoring the view, and introducing a `ModelForm`

The line above:

```
userdata = User.objects.get(username = request.user)
```

makes no sense either: the `request.user` *is* a `User` object, so it is equivalent to:

```
userdata = request.user
```

Other piculiarities in the view are that you perform authentication yourself, instead of using the [**`@login_required`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator), and furthermore it here definitely makes sense to define a [**`ModelForm`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform), by using a form, the view will probably be reduced to 5-7 lines, and the errors are handled at the correct place.

Comment: @login_required(login_url="/login/") i use this for authentication

Comment: @MõñaSingh: If you wrote a custom authentication system, then you should use a `reverse_lazy(..)` mapping to the view, if not, `@login_required` is sufficient.

Comment: but i want hear who will create the checqu hear that will save in that partcular user account not show to all other users that why i make relation  hear but when i use above no related then all details save in no related field

Comment: i mean if u are the user that the infomation of you is confidentials for only you not public

Comment: @MõñaSingh: well in your view it is not clear at all what `passwd` is (it looks like it does not exists at all). Furthermore the point of `@login_required` is that it exactly enforces that. Lastly your view does not link the registered user at all. You need ot pass a reference in the construction, which is not possible, since you did not construct a `Signs` object either.

Comment: @MõñaSingh: this is - imho - the result of poor modeling, and the view is not really following any design patterns at all.

Comment: Your `Signs` class seems to "act" like a `Profile`, but it has a many-to-one relation to a user, and furthermore in the provided code, you never construct such `Signs` at all.

Comment: u mean if admin user make somthing then it will save in not related field but any reigistered user do somthing then it will save in another field plz clear this to me am getting confuse now

Comment: @MõñaSingh: that is why in case of admins, etc. you will need an extra field that specifies the user. But right now it is indeed completely unclear what exactly you aim to do since we are stuck in the **XY** problem: you specify *how* you want to solve something, not *what* you want to solve.

Comment: i easily register the users but not login i dnt know why but when i use authntication it will not login but without using authentictaion i easily login the registered users

Comment: @MõñaSingh: but that's "circumventing" the problem, which in the end will only result in more trouble. You should try to find out what is going wrong with the authentication. Checking credentials oneself in every view, is a security vulnerability.

Comment: ok i will try to find the problem why this happens thanks for help Willem Van Onsem.